# Continuity of a function "preserves" some of its properties in neighborhoods

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

To begin with, I apologize for the title of the question since it sounds too vague but I couldn't think of anything better at the moment. I hope the rest of the post is clear...

> Assume that $g \in C(M)$ where $M$ is some compact subset of $\mathbb
>  R^3\;.$ If, for a fixed positive constant $C>0\;,$ it holds
> $\begin{align} (1-g(x))-f(t)g(x) \geq \frac{C}{2} \qquad \text{for
>  all} \quad x\in U \quad \text{and} \quad t\in [a,b] \end{align}$
>
> for some bounded and closed subset $U \subset M\;,$ **then by
> continuity of $g$** there exists a neighborhood $U_\delta$ of $U$ ($\delta>0$) such
> that $\begin{align} (1-g(x))-f(t)g(x) \geq \frac{C}{4} \qquad
>  \text{for all} \quad x\in U_\delta \quad \text{and} \quad t\in
>  [a,b]\;. \end{align}$
>
> Note that $f\in L^{\infty}(a,b)$ and $0<k_1 \leq f(t) \leq k_2$ for all $t\in [a,b]\;$.

Although I can understand this by intuition, I would like to be able to derive it formally as well. Hence, I thought of the following:

$\begin{align}
\text{Let} \; y\in U_\delta\;, x\in U \;: &(1-g(y))-f(t)g(y)+f(t)g(x)-f(t)g(x) \\&=(1-g(y))-f(t)g(x)+f(t)(g(x)-g(y)) \\ &\geq\min \limits_{y \in U_\delta}\{ (1-g(y))\}-f(t)g(x)-f(t)\vert g(x)-g(y)\vert \\ &\geq \min \limits_{x \in U}\{ (1-g(x))-f(t)g(x)\}-k_2 \varepsilon \;,
\end{align}$

if $\delta>0$ is sufficiently small. Then, choosing $\varepsilon:=\frac{C}{4k_2}>0$, we deduce that $(1-g(y))-f(t)g(y) \geq \frac{C}{4} \qquad \text{for all} \quad y\in U_\delta \quad \text{and} \quad t\in [a,b]\;$.

Is the above consideration correct? I would appreciate if someone could verify this argument or fix any misunderstandings and wrong points.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Please add to your question what $f$ is. This is an essential information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really follow your equalities. But there's another way.

This follows from the simple observation that if $h:X\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous and $h(x)>C$ over some subset $A\subseteq X$ then $h(x)>C$ over some open neighbourhood $U$ of $A$. This works for any topological space $X$. The neighbourhood we are looking for is simply $U:=h^{-1}((C,\infty))$.

Now in your case if $f$ is continuous (which you didn't say but I assume it is the case) then we consider $X=M\times [a,b]$ with $h(x,t)=1-g(x)-f(t)g(x)$ which is continuous. Then we apply the above to $\frac{C}{4}$ (note that we get even stronger, strict inequality "$>\frac{C}{4}$").

**EDIT:** if $f$ is not continuous then it still holds as long as it is positive and bounded. Indeed, our original inequality can be written as

$$1-g(x)\big(1+f(t)\big)\geq \frac{C}{2}$$
$$g(x)\big(1+f(t)\big)-1\leq -\frac{C}{2}$$
$$g(x)\leq (1-\frac{C}{2})/(1+f(t))$$

And so for $M=\sup_{t\in [a,b]} f(t)$ we have

$$g(x)\leq (1-\frac{C}{2})/(1+M)$$

By continuity this extends to

$$g(x)< (1-\frac{C}{4})/(1+M)$$

(note "$4$") over some open neighbourhood. Then we can reverse the process to get

$$g(x)< (1-\frac{C}{4})/(1+f(t))$$

which then easily leads to the desired result, again with the strict inequality.

Comment: thanks a lot for your time but $f$ here is not continuous, it belongs only in $L^\infty$...

Comment: @kaithkolesidou A function in $L^\infty$ is almost continuous anyway.

Comment: @kaithkolesidou actually the continuity of $f$ is irrelevant. I've updated the answer.

Comment: This approach seems to suit me better at the moment. Thanks again!